# How do I change the theme, (iconset) on a Galaxy S3 default launcher?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, themes, samsung-galaxy-s-3

I bought a Galaxy S3 (Android 4).

I downloaded the user manual, and I can't find a way to change the appearance.  I **can** change the wallpaper and the font size, but I **can't** change drawer transition behavior, the general UI theme or the icon set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download Apex launcher--

It has full support for themes and transitions, icons, etc-

For Icon packs, "ADW Icons" is a good keyword to use- since Apex will use ADW icons.

Comment: Brilliant, thats the trick

Answer (score 0):

You could also go with [Go Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gau.go.launcherex), amongst many other choices.